# CompletableFuture doesn't work with thenAccept

Tags: java, flux, completable-future

```
Stream<String> stream = Stream.of("hello", "world");
CompletableFuture<Flux<Integer>> future =
        new CompletableFuture<>();
future.supplyAsync(() -> Flux.fromStream(stream))
        .thenApply(flux -> flux.map(s -> s + " processed"))
        .thenAccept(System.out::println);

sleep(1000);
```

I expected to get a output of `Hello processed` and `World processed` but it returns `FluxMapFuseable`. What is wrong with above code?

Comment: Your code doesn't make any sense to me. Why would you wrap a reactive type inside a future? Anyways, `thenAccept` should be `thenAccept(flux -> flux.log().subscribe())`. On the other hand, the above code might seem to work but it has wrong types specified and assignment would fail. `CompletableFuture<Flux<Integer>>` should be `CompletableFuture<Flux<String>>`.

Comment: In addition to @Aniket's comment, `supplyAsync()` is actually a static method, so you should call it using `CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(…)`.